# Android admob ads not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-tabhost

So I feel it might be a layout issue in my main.xml file.  I am in no way an xml expert. I experimented with the test app from admob and was able to get it to display ads so I know it is not an issue with the publisher ID.  Below is the contents of my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.project.testsoundboard"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <com.google.ads.AdView 
                       android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="320dip"
                       android:layout_height="48dip"
                      ads:adUnitId="a28d9e354361jf3"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <GridView 
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="2dp" android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp" android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center" />
            <GridView android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="2dp" android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp" android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center" />
            <GridView android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="2dp" android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp" android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Here is my attrs.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
  <attr name="adSize">
      <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
      <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
      <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
      <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
  </attr>
  <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
```

I added the appropriate permissions in the manifest file as well

There is spacing above the tabs from the layout_width and layout_height I specified in the main.xml layout file but nothing appears.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that your framelayout is also trying to fill parent, so even though you explicitly gave a size for your ad, it might be getting squeezed out.

If that doesn't help, you might try removing everything except for the ad, and ad the other elements until you find what causes it to break.